# How can I "fix" my transmission-gtk state after having moved the download directory?

Tags: linux, bittorrent, transmission, move

Suppose you use the transmission-gtk BitTorrent client (v2.94) on a Linux system to seed some files, e.g. Linux distribution ISOs and LibreOffice versions. Suppose that the basic "Save To Location" is: `/path1/torrents` and the incomplete torrents path is `/path1/torrents/incomplete`.

Now suppose that you shut down transmission-gtk, and rename `/path1` to `/path2` (and do not symlink the old path to the new one).

It is simple to change the location for future torrents using the app's configuration dialog, or in `$HOME/.config/transmission`. However, when one does this, all previously-active torrents are now marked red, with data supposedly missing.

What should one do to correct the locations for existing torrents (complete and incomplete)? And - can this be automated somehow so that it could be done from the command line (e.g. on files in `$HOME/.config/transmission/resume`)?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the torrent, click "Set Location" and select the new parent directory (`/path2/torrents` in this case). You can do this for all torrents at once, if they all were moved to the same directory.

After updating the location, right-click again and select "Verify local data" to let Transmission recheck which files/parts have been already downloaded.

---

This is automatable from CLI – but first enable the "web UI" feature in Transmission, which also allows you to use `transmission-remote`.

For each torrent, run `transmission-remote --find` with the new parent directory.

---

The files in ~/.config/transmission/resume/ are in the same "Bencode" format as .torrent files themselves, and they could probably be modified using e.g. Perl's Convert::Bencode or very careful sed'ing, but I'm not sure if I would recommend that method.

You'd want to update the "destination" item in the top-level dict:

```
$ bencode2json < 16a3968b347a81845384394e7f1b38656aeee97a.resume | head
{
    "activity-date": "1619012434",
    "added-date": "1619011497",
    "bandwidth-priority": "0",
    "corrupt": "0",
    "destination": "/home/xxx/Downloads",
    "dnd": [
    ...
```

(If you go with direct binary editing, note that Bencoded strings are prefixed with their length which needs to be updated as well, e.g. `19:/home/xxx/Downloads` in this case.)

Comment: When torrents have multiple files, they're put in a subdirectory under `torrents/`. Should I, or should I not, include the torrent-specific subdir in the choice of the new root?

Comment: No, you should choose only the parent directory in all cases. The subdirectory is part of the torrent's "contents".

Answer (score 2):

An addition to @user1686's great answer: You can update the location of all torrents at once:

- Select "All" and "All" in the to "Show:" bar (so that all torrents are visible).
- Press Ctrl+A to select all visible torrents.
- Right-click any of the selected torrents.
- Select "Set Location".
- Choose "Other".
- Navigate to the new folder for torrents (in your case "/path2/torrents").
- Select "Local data is already there".
- Click "Apply".
- Wait a while for the torrents to be updated.
- When the dialog has disappeared, restart transmission-gtk.

Your torrents should all be recognized as resumeable. You still have to actually resume them though - they're auto-paused if the data couldn't be found.